# TemplateSyntaxError at endfor in jinja django coding

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

`jinja2` is not recognizing `{% endfor %}` and runs into this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at endfor in jinja django coding
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
{% for dest in dests % }
               
  <!-- Destination -->
  <div class="destination item">
    <div class="destination_image">
      <img src="{{im}}/{{dest.img}}" alt="">
      <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="destination_content">
      <div class="destination_title"><a href="{% static 'destinations.html' %}">{{dest.name}}</a></div>
      <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{dest.desc}}</p></div>
      <div class="destination_price">From ${{dest.price}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Here `dest` is a list which is displaying the content.

Comment: Please show us error. Also what is {{im}} in <img>?

Comment: {% for dest in dests %``you_have_space_here``}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recognizing the forloop because your jinja formatting is wrong.Cannot have space at start and end of percentage.Change to this`{% for dest in dests %}`.

when you are getting images for database you need .url at the end. So you code should look like  `<img src="{{dest.img.url}}" alt="">`